# Where does one go to vote for an EOS BP?

Tags: voting, bp

I checked eosauthority wallet and no where can I find a place to vote for a BP. How does one vote for a BP with scatter?

Answer (score 1):

Since EOS is a distributed project, there is no one central official place to vote.
There are several different ways to vote for Block Producers on the EOS mainnet.

The first is using the command line tool, cleos:

`cleos system voteproducer approve votername producername`

The more user friendly ways involve a signing tool like scatter and a web site.
One of the websites that allows you to easily vote is https://bloks.io/vote

Answer (score 1):

Many of the explorers/bps/tools have voting feature using Scatter. Some are here:

[EOS Authority](https://eosauthority.com/vote/producers)

[EOSX.IO](https://eosx.io/tools/vote)

[Bloks.IO](https://bloks.io/vote)

Login using your accountname on scatter and you can cast your votes to BPs or a proxy.